# How to pass multiple parameters in json format to a web service using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to execute a asp.net webservice using jquery. When I pass only one input parameter it works fine:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: url,  
    data: "{'Id1':'2'}",  
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: callback
});
```

but if  I try to pass multiple parameters it fails

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: url,  
    data: "{'Id1':'2'},{'Id2':'2'}",  
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: callback
});
```

Of course, when I try to pass 2 input parameters, I modify the web method so that it takes 2 input parameters.

Any ideas?

Comment: We need to see the ASP code that parses the JSON object POST parameter.

Comment: modify ur URL
url=url+'?param1='+value1+'&&param2='+value2;
this might serve u

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Found the solution:

It should be:

```
"{'Id1':'2','Id2':'2'}"
```

and not

```
"{'Id1':'2'},{'Id2':'2'}"
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a stab in the dark, but maybe do you need to wrap your JSON arguments; like say something like this:

```
data: "{'Ids':[{'Id1':'2'},{'Id2':'2'}]}"
```

Make sure your JSON is properly formed?

Answer (score 4):

i have same issue and resolved  by

```
 data: "Id1=" + id1 + "&Id2=" + id2
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is:

```
data: "{'Ids':['2','2']}"
```

To read this values Ids[0], Ids[1].