# Getting form data values in json format

Tags: json, jquery

How do you get the value of an html element attr for an ajax call?

my code:

```
$('#manager_pass').submit(function(evt){ 

    evt.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({

            url: App.managerpassURL,
            data: {
                ????????????
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(r){
                box_2.animate({'top':'-250px'},500,function(){
                overlay.fadeOut('fast');
                    $('.action_wrapper').fadeOut(1000, function(){
                            $('.form').fadeIn(1000);
                    });
                });
            }


        });

});
```

I need to get the value from here

```
<input type="text" name="managerPassword" value="" class="man_code">
```

Thanks

Comment: I need to get the value from my input field inside my data object             data: { ???????????? },

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if you want to send JSON:

```
JSON.stringify({ "pass" : $('input[name="managerPassword"]').val() })
```

Of course make sure its secured if you want to send a password!

Comment: data: {
                       JSON.stringify({ "pass" : $('input[name="managerPassword"]').val(); })
                },

Comment: You should try `data : JSON.stringify({ "pass" : $('input[name="managerPassword"]').val() })`

Comment: not working :( data : JSON.stringify({ "pass" : $('input[name="managerPassword"]').val() }),

Comment: What's the error? can you try printing to the console `console.log(JSON.stringify({ "pass" : $('input[name="managerPassword"]').val() }))` just before you are calling `$.ajax` and tell us what you see?

Comment: success: function(r){
                box_2.animate({'top':'-250px'},500,function(){
                overlay.fadeOut('fast');
                    $('.action_wrapper').fadeOut(1000, function(){
                            $('.form').fadeIn(1000);
                    });
                });
            }

Comment: {"pass":"dddsa3321"} 77b7abdc35:654
XHR finished loading: "http://projectURL". jquery.min.js:2
send jquery.min.js:2
p.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) 77b7abdc35:656
p.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:2
g.handle.h

Comment: Looks like the AJAX part is working then, you'll need to look into why the stuff in the success callback are failing. I'm not sure what box_2 or overlay are in this context...

Comment: hi overlay and box2 simply replace id values inside html nothing more

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17186/discussion-between-ramsinb-and-alex)

Answer (score 0):

If you specify an `id` attribute on your input element, you can do the following to get the value in js:

```
document.getElementById('exampleid').value
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#manager_pass').submit(function(evt){

```
evt.preventDefault();
var passtxt=$('input:text[name=managerPassword]').val();
    $.ajax({

        url: App.managerpassURL,
        data: {
            passtxt:passtxt
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(r){
            box_2.animate({'top':'-250px'},500,function(){
            overlay.fadeOut('fast');
                $('.action_wrapper').fadeOut(1000, function(){
                        $('.form').fadeIn(1000);
                });
            });
        }


    });
```

});

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503627/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-in-json-format-to-a-web-service-using-jquery try in this way it may help you if JSON.stringify does not work